# Add current element in array + next element in array while iterating through array in Python

Tags: python, arrays

What's the best way to add the first element in an array to the next element in the same array, then add the result to the next element of the array, and so on? For example, I have an array:

```
s=[50, 1.2658, 1.2345, 1.2405, 1.2282, 1.2158, 100]
```

I would like the end array to look like the following:

```
new_s=[50, 51.2658, 52.5003, 53.7408, 54.969, 56.1848, 100]
```

Thus leaving the minimum and maximum elements of the array unchanged.

I started going this route:

```
arr_length=len(s)
new_s=[50]

for i, item in enumerate(s):
     if i == 0:
         new_s.append(new_s[i]+s[i+1])
     elif 0<i<=(arr_length-2):
         new_s.append(new_s[i]+s[i+1])
```

Currently I get the following list:

```
new_s=[50, 51.2658, 52.5003, 53.7408, 54.969, 56.1848, 156.1848]
```

What am I doing wrong that isn't leaving the last item unchanged?

Comment: @AndrewL. He does not want to change the last element

Comment: Didn't see that, my mistake @VaibhavBajaj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The beset way is using `numpy.cumsum()` for all of your items except the last one then append the last one to the result of `cumsum()`:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> s=[50, 1.2658, 1.2345, 1.2405, 1.2282, 1.2158, 100]
>>> 
>>> np.append(np.cumsum(s[:-1]), s[-1])
array([  50.    ,   51.2658,   52.5003,   53.7408,   54.969 ,   56.1848,
        100.    ])
```

Or with python (3.X) use `itertools.accumulate()`:

```
>>> import itertools as it
>>> 
>>> list(it.accumulate(s[:-1])) + s[-1:]
[50, 51.2658, 52.500299999999996, 53.74079999999999, 54.968999999999994, 56.184799999999996, 100]
```

Comment: I am afraid this is not what he wants. He wants the last element to stay the same

Comment: He isn't using numpy, so why the extra library?

Comment: @AndrewL. Just updated the answer. I just tried to give the best answer.

Comment: I'm just not sure why you need an external library to accomplish this. Sure, it's easier, but the OP doesn't mention the use of numPy

Comment: Works great! Thanks, it's also much cleaner than my loop.

Comment: @AndrewL. Because Numpy is extremely faster than python (for huge data sets)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `numpy.cumsum()`:

```
import numpy as np
np.append(np.cumsum(s[:-1]), s[-1])
# array([50., 51.2658, 52.5003, 53.7408, 54.969 , 56.1848, 100.])
```